# Search for deaths by a specific drug

Tags: openfda

I am not a programmer, so I am trying to understand the search methods to use when looking at OpenFDA. I am currently using the generic form for Reported Reactions. How do you get more the 10 adverse events and how do you get deaths to show up?

Comment: Could you add a bit about what you've done so far? It's easier to troubleshoot, or just give you a better answer in general, that way.

Comment: if you are not a programmer, perhaps use the full data table rather than the api  http://www.fda.gov/Drugs/GuidanceComplianceRegulatoryInformation/Surveillance/AdverseDrugEffects/ucm082193.htm

Answer (score 6):

Here are two ways to do your query:

- Using the OpenFDA API directly by specifying a `brand_name` and `reactionmedrapt` value: [https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.brand_name:(tysabri)+AND+patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt:(death)&limit=50&skip=0](https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.brand_name%3a%28tysabri%29+AND+patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt%3a%28death%29&limit=50&skip=0)
- Using a tool I helped build which is a searchable web interface to the OpenFDA data at http://openfdasearch.herokuapp.com/?drugbrandname=tysabri&patient_reaction=death

Hope this helps!